# Python os.mkdir weirdly not working in certain situations

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I've been struggling for hours with this issue.

To explain quickly I'm currently working on a small script and I wanted to make so my program produce logs. So I've made a small code that verify if the directory and the log file alread exists and if not creates them. However when I'm running this code with **Pycharm**, **Visual Studio** or by **CMD** it simply doesn't work. For python the directory was successfully created and os.listdir() shows that it has been created. However in reality it doesn't appear anywhere in my roaming, it's not visible either by Windows File Explorer or by my CMD.

And what is even STRANGER is that when I'm running my python file by double clicking ont it, it suddenly runs just fine and create my file ?? I could just satisfy myself that it works in this specifc scenario but I kind want it to work on it from Pycharm in order to continue on my project...

Here's the portion of code that I described earlier.

Thanks for your advices !

```
import os
import logging
import shutil


logPath = os.path.join(os.environ.get('APPDATA'), 'DesktopCleaner', 'log.txt')
desktopCleanerPath = os.path.join(os.environ.get('APPDATA'), 'DesktopCleaner')

print(os.path.isdir(desktopCleanerPath))

if not os.path.isdir(desktopCleanerPath):
    os.makedirs(desktopCleanerPath)

if not os.path.isfile(logPath):
    open(logPath, "a").close()

logging.basicConfig(filename=logPath, filemode="w", format="%(asctime)s - %(message)s")
```

Comment: How are you looking?  The `AppData\Roaming` folder is hidden by default, and won't show up in Explorer.  There's no way this can fail, so the problem has to be in the way you are looking.  And, BTW, since you're guaranteed that `%APPDATA%` exists, you don't need `os.makedirs`.  `os.mkdir` will work just as well.

Comment: Yeah no problem accessing `AppData\Roaming` I can see all the files in it. The problem is that it only create the directory `DesktopCleaner` in  `AppData\Roaming` when I double click on my script and it absolutly doesn't work with Pycharm and cie. I previously used `os.mkdir` but it didn't worked so I tried to use `os.makedirs` but the issue is exactly the same. I'm 100% sure I'm correctly searching through my Roaming since I can see the directory be created when I double click the script.

Comment: You could `print(logPath)` and after basicConfig, do `assert os.path.isifle(logPath), "log file created"`. That gives you more information on the file.

Comment: If you do `set APPDATA`, does it show you what you expect?  In corporate environments, APPPDATA sometimes gets redirectred.

Comment: So `print(logPath)` prints me `C:\Users\elgem\AppData\Roaming\DesktopCleaner\log.txt`

`assert os.path.isfile(logPath)` doesn't raise any error.

`set APPDATA` ouputs in `APPDATA=C:\Users\elgem\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: I made some more tests and my script is able to generate directories and files just fine as long as they are outside of my appdata. For now I'm just going to save my logs elsewhere but I'm puzzled by this strange issue.